# Express JS get Params

Tags: node.js, express

Who can I get parameters? If I have a get URL in expressjs like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/verify-password-reset?auth_token=a944d6141&user_email=example@gmail.com
```

I got the first value auth_token using req.params

```
router.get('/verify-password-reset', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.auth_token);
  console.log(req.query.email);
```

}

But email is undefined.

How can I get the email if it has a & in the URL? I tried using docs but couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: the problem is email is undefined

Comment: You don't say. Maybe because it's called `user_email` and not `email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean params the url looks like this for example: `'/example/:id'` which **id** is the the parameter that you specify and you can get its value like this: `req.params.id`

In your case you are using a QueryString, so you should use this: `req.query.user_email` which `user_email` is your **key** in the url.